# How to pass values between multiple testng xml files each running in different threads

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, parallel-processing, testng, thread-local

In selenium, I am doing parallel execution of multiple xml files using ThreadLocal concept. Now, I want to make communication between threads that:

1. TestA in xml1 is passed.
2. TestA in xml2 should be executed when TestA in xml1 is passed. Until then, I need to wait xml2's thread.

I tried with dependencies, but it tells only within xml file.

Please note, I am working in a Product that has different modules with nearly 10k Test cases. It takes a whole day to complete run with the current ThreadLocal concept.

I want to minimize the execution time. Kindly state any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, how it fits in your case but you can use groups in your tests and 
`you can specify your group dependencies in the testng.xml file(s).`

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Test Suite for End To End">
    <test name="AUT_E2E_01">
        <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" />
        <classes>
            <class name="com.myunit.regressiontests">
                <methods>
                    <include name="Test1" />
                    <include name="Test11" dependsOnMethods="SomeMethod" />
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
        <groups>
            <dependencies>
                <group name="SomeOther-Group" depends-on="Some-Group" />
            </dependencies>
        </groups>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: in the case of single test case failure, will the entire group be re-run ??

Comment: It will execute based on dependency tree you define, and that should be ideal expectation I suppose.